# Restrict user to input 2 spaces at same time Flutter Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I am trying to restrict user from double spaces at same time i searched and found in textfield we can use inputFormatter to Block any key in keyboard.

I used this RegExp to block double spaces
its working fine , the space button doesn't work when last character is space but when i type next character then its just remove spaces from textfield.

```
BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(
searchText.substring(searchText.length-1) == " "

? RegExp('[\\-|\\/\|\\:|\\ ]')

: RegExp('[\\-|\\/\|\\:]')),
```

Answer (score 1):

To restrict user to add 2 or more space together

In below **Allow RegExp** ther is one space in end and **Deny RegExp** there is two space

user this input formatter;-

```
inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[a-z A-Z á-ú Á-Ú 0-9 ]')),FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny('  ')],
```

you can adjust/update allow and deny RegExp accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: this way you can check the last typed character then update widget state based on that:

```dart
//...
bool _isBlockedSpaceKey = false;
//...
TextField(
   // ...
   onChanged:(value) {
      setState(() {
         _isBlockedSpaceKey = value.endsWith(' ');
      });
   }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for response i did used trip() and it's used to remove spaces at start and end of String, if the space is removed how can i check if last character is a white space or another character ? I did tried what you said but when white space at end is removed length of String will be decrease which return RangeError

Comment: make sense because ```searchText.length-1``` is not exist anymore. but why you still checking this ```searchText.substring(searchText.length-1) == " "```, isn't after trimming the only left RegExp is this ```RegExp('[\\-|\\/\|\\:]')```?, so it's always: ```BlacklistingTextInputFormatter(RegExp('[\\-|\\/\|\\:]'))```?

Comment: also you can check if a string has a white-space using this: ```bool containsSpace = 'some string'.contains(' '); // true```

Comment: i want to check searchText container white space at end or not, if user input white space at end then i want to block space button for next input if it's not white space then user can input space, string.contains(' ') will check if the enter string have white space or not, for now i just used searchText = val.replaceAll(RegExp(r"\s+\b|\b\s"), " "); to replace multiple whitespace to single white space.

Comment: check the updated answer, I think I got your idea. am I?

Comment: i tried updated code and i tried this before too, if i last character is white space and i input a number then it just remove white space from text